# Automated internet explorer in Excel to search multiple items on a site

Tags: vba, excel, ie-automation

I am using excel 2013 with a worksheet containing a column of license numbers.

The macro needs to cycle through each cell to be searched on the webpage. 
Once searched it grabs some details from the search result page and puts it in the cell next to the license number.

The problem I am encountering is that not all the license numbers are going to be found which results in the web site throwing an error and not going to the results page which results in code failure.

I need a way to skip the license number that throws the webpage error and the continue on to the next entry.

The other problem that is really more of a headache is that the results that are inserted into the cells comes from a table format, so it makes the cells massive and throws off the workbook formatting. Is there a way to either grab only specific details from the search result or to make sure it puts it in an "unwrapped" format?

**Details for recreating the macro.**

The website needs you to create a free username and password but once created should have a cookie saved, so the code does not include a login portion.

Webpage search location (after login): https://aca3.accela.com/MILARA/GeneralProperty/PropertyLookUp.aspx?isLicensee=Y&TabName=APO

The error page: https://aca3.accela.com/MILARA/Error.aspx?ErrorId=2d09a60802d2455b8fbf1b86e45033d2

```
    Sub SearchPage()

    Dim IE As Object
    Dim search As Variant
    Dim button As Variant
    Dim LR As Integer
    Dim var As String
    Dim var1 As Object
    Dim CurrentWindow As HTMLWindowProxy

    LR = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    For x = 2 To LR
    var = Cells(x, 1).Value

    Set IE = CreateObject("internetexplorer.application")
    IE.Visible = True

    With IE
    .Visible = True
    .navigate "https://aca3.accela.com/MILARA/GeneralProperty/PropertyLookUp.aspx?isLicensee=Y&TabName=APO"

    While Not .readyState = READYSTATE_COMPLETE
    Wend
    End With

            'Wait some to time for loading the page

    While IE.Busy
    DoEvents
    Wend

    Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:02"))
            'this is where it puts the number from the cell into the search box
'below is the text search box and the cell containing the ID    IE.document.getElementById("ctl00_PlaceHolderMain_refLicenseeSearchForm_txtLicenseNumber").Value = var
            'Here we are clicking on search Button
    IE.document.getElementById("ctl00_PlaceHolderMain_btnNewSearch").Click

            'wait for page to load
    Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:02"))
    While IE.Busy
    DoEvents
    Wend


            'grabs results from search and places it in cell next to searched id

    Set var1 = IE.document.getElementById("ctl00_PlaceHolderMain_upGeneralInfo")
    Cells(x, 2).Value = var1.innerText

    IE.Quit
    Set IE = Nothing

    Next x
    End Sub
```

Comment: I have resolved how to identify and grab the specific instances out of the search result table, however I am still having trouble getting the macro to skip a search that results in the error page.

Comment: I am not sure why this got a down vote. I did research, included code, and tried my best to give a concise description of the goal. If people are going to discredit my question it would be nice to have some feedback as to why. Especially since your scores affect your ability to ask questions.

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub SearchPage()

Dim IE As Object
Dim search As Variant
Dim button As Variant
Dim LR As Integer
Dim var As String
Dim var1 As Object
Dim var2 As Object
Dim var3 As Object
Dim var4 As Object
Dim var5 As Object
Dim var6 As Object

Dim CurrentWindow As HTMLWindowProxy
 On Error Resume Next
LR = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
For x = 2 To LR
var = Cells(x, 1).Value

Set IE = CreateObject("internetexplorer.application")
IE.Visible = False

With IE
.Visible = False

.navigate "https://aca3.accela.com/MILARA/GeneralProperty/PropertyLookUp.aspx?isLicensee=Y&TabName=APO"

While Not .readyState = READYSTATE_COMPLETE
Wend
End With

        'Wait some to time for loading the page

While IE.Busy
DoEvents
Wend

Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:02"))
        'this is where it puts the number from the cell into the search box
IE.document.getElementById("ctl00_PlaceHolderMain_refLicenseeSearchForm_txtLicenseNumber").Value = var
        'Here we are clicking on search Button
IE.document.getElementById("ctl00_PlaceHolderMain_btnNewSearch").Click

        'wait for page to load
Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:01"))
While IE.Busy
DoEvents
Wend




                'grabs table
'Set var1 = IE.document.getElementById("ctl00_PlaceHolderMain_upGeneralInfo")
'Cells(x, 2).Value = var1.innerText

                'grabs name
              Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:01"))

Set var2 = IE.document.getElementById("ctl00_PlaceHolderMain_licenseeGeneralInfo_lblContactName_value")
Cells(x, 3).Value = var2.innerText

        Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:01"))

                'grabs Issue date
Set var3 = IE.document.getElementById("ctl00_PlaceHolderMain_licenseeGeneralInfo_lblLicenseIssueDate_value")
Cells(x, 4).Value = var3.innerText

        Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:01"))

                'grabs expiration date
Set var4 = IE.document.getElementById("ctl00_PlaceHolderMain_licenseeGeneralInfo_lblExpirationDate_value")
Cells(x, 5).Value = var4.innerText

        Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:01"))

                'license status
Set var5 = IE.document.getElementById("ctl00_PlaceHolderMain_licenseeGeneralInfo_lblBusinessName2_value")
Cells(x, 6).Value = var5.innerText

 Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:01"))

                'grab url
'Set var6 = IE.LocationURL
'Cells(x, 7).Value = var6.innerText


IE.Quit
Set IE = Nothing
Next x

'Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:02"))

MsgBox ("Verification Import Complete")



End Sub
```